# How to to write to a text file using list box

Tags: c#, stream

I have a text file "cars.txt" that is saved in a bin\debug and I would like to add more care models to it using C# and display the whole content of the file with new added lines. How do I do that?

```
string[] models = new string[] { "Toyota", "Nissan" };

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("CarsList.txt"))
{
    foreach (string s in models)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(s);
        listBoxCars.Items.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: [File.AppendText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext). It returns a `StreamWriter`. You can then use the `WriteLine` method to add new lines to the existing ones.

Comment: Are you just saving Brands or Models as well? If both, you may want to look at saving it as an XML file (look at XmlDocument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, the easiest of which might be to just pass `true` as a second parameter to your `StreamWriter` constructor, which instructs it to append text:

```
string[] models = { "Toyota", "Nissan" };

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("CarsList.txt", true))
{
    foreach (string s in models)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

You can then easily get the entire file contents into a string using `File.ReadAllText`:

```
string fileContents = File.ReadAllText("CarsList.txt");
```

Or if you want to read in each line as a separate item, you can use `File.ReadAllLines` (note that this is **not** inside the `using` block above - this should be after that part has completed and the new items are added to the file):

```
foreach (var item in File.ReadAllLines(fileName))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer and it didn't work, it displays only Toyota and Nissan in the list box, not other strings that already existed on the file.

Comment: Well, you're not adding any other strings to the listbox, you're only adding the items that we're writing to the file. Do you want to display the file in the listbox, then?

Comment: If you want to write the contents of the file to a listbox, follow the last sample in the answer above (and remove the line that adds an item when writing to the file).

Comment: yes, I want to display the whole thing in the list box

Comment: I actually figure it out and the list box displays everything I used StreamReader. Thank you so much